# "The requested fetchSize is more than the allowed value in Athena" with JDBC driver

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-athena

I'm trying to pull data from an Athena DB into R using `RJDBC` as described in detail on [AWS's own blog](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/big-data/running-r-on-amazon-athena/). Alas, the amount of data I'm trying to pull is substantial and so I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error in .jcall(rp, "I", "fetch", stride, block) : 
  java.sql.SQLException: The requested fetchSize is more than the allowed value in Athena. Please reduce the fetchSize and try again. Refer to the Athena documentation for valid fetchSize values.
```

The Athena documentation doesn't actually give any such `fetchSize` values but I gather from [this github issue](https://github.com/s-u/RJDBC/issues/44) that the value should be lower than 1000. I gather from the same github issue that there is no way to pass this `fetchSize` to RJDBC. So are there other ways of querying Athena that respect this limit?

Comment: Do you know what the underlying query is?

Comment: Yes, I know what the query is. It should return a few hundred thousand rows.

Comment: This is a lot of data.  Can you limit the amount of data, and possibly fetch everything over several queries?

Comment: It's ~70MB if I pull it as a CSV instead. That hardly seems prohibitive.

Comment: Agreed +1.  I know SQL, but not this API, maybe someone else can help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic problem is that `dbGetQuery` doesn't allow one to specify the `fetchSize`. As [per the `RJDBC` package author](https://github.com/s-u/RJDBC/issues/44) one workaround is to call the two functions that `dbGetQuery` wraps separately and pass the `fetchSize` to `fetch()`:

```
q <- dbSendQuery(c, ...)
fetch(q, -1, block=999)
```

More generally:

```
setMethod("dbGetQuery", signature(conn="JDBCConnection", statement="character"),  def=function(conn, statement, ...) {
  r <- dbSendQuery(conn, statement, ...)
  on.exit(.jcall(r@stat, "V", "close"))
  if (conn@jc %instanceof% "com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaConnection") fetch(r, -1, 999) # Athena can only pull 999 rows at a time
  else fetch(r, -1)
})
```

Comment: Great! Works for me too!

Comment: `%instanceof%` and `.jcall` are functions from `rJava` pacakge

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I fixed this in the `AWR.Athena` R package, so you can use it if you like.

Answer (score 0):

From `RJDBC version >= 0.2-10` you can use dbGetQuery with `n = -1` and `block = 999` to fetch more than 1000 lines from Athena:

```
d = dbGetQuery(con, statement = "select * from tmp limit 1001", n = -1, block = 999)
```